# Why does BinaryWriter append unwanted character to the end of a xml file in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am using below code for writing xml file.

`Dim downloadFile As New FileInfo("c:\test.xml")
         Using bw As New BinaryWriter(downloadFile.OpenWrite)
           bw.Write(Buffer) 'Buffer is Byte array
           bw.Close()
         End Using`

but in each file, there is unwanted character(as showing snapshot) is coming at the end of file.
[image: unwanted character]

how to avoid this during writing to the file.

Comment: It's nothing to do with BinaryWriter, the final byte in your array has a value of 0 (nullchar).

Comment: can we delete it after writing it to file using regular expression? or any other way?

Comment: You could simply use bw.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length-1).  But focus a bit on where that 0 came from first.

Comment: not working  bw.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length-1) for this. even after this change NUL is coming at the end of file.

Comment: That's because `.OpenWrite` only overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you are writing a shorter string than what is already in the file then the existing characters will remain at the end.

Comment: i am writing in the new files, in which there are no existing characters.